# Building a static library in C

Tags: c, gcc, dll, static

I have two sources I'd like to combine into one C static library.

```
renderay_core.c
renderay_shapes.c
```

and its corresponding header files. I compiled this as standalone (non library) first to avoid errors here.

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "renderay_core.c"
#include "renderay_shapes.c"

int main(void){ 
  Canvas* canvas = new_Canvas(5,5);
  printf("Test");
}
```

compiled it with:

```
gcc test.c renderay_core.c renderay_shapes.c -o main.exe
```

and it worked fine.

Now I'm up to pack this into a static lib. Doing as followed:

```
gcc -c renderay_core.c renderay_shapes.c
```

Now I have the objects ready to be linked as a library.

```
ar rcs librenderay.a renderay_core.c renderay_shapes.c
```

Is the command I use for this. Then I try to compile my test.c with the library instead of the plain source files.

```
gcc test.c -o main.exe -static -L -lrenderay
```

Now when I try to compile this I get a error warning:

> undefined reference to "new_Canvas"

Telling me that the linking to the library failed. What am I doing wrong here? What did I missed out?

Comment: Learn about header files. Don't include implementation files.

Comment: You appear to be running `ar` against the C source files rather than the object files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile - without linking - the source files

```
gcc -c renderay_core.c -o renderay_core.o
gcc -c renderay_shapes.c -o renderay_shapes.o
```

Then pack it

```
ar -rcs librenderay.a renderay_core.o renderay_shapes.o
```

And link to it using

```
gcc test.c -o main.exe -static -L. -lrenderay
```

You need the `L` to specify the nonstandard location - current directory here.

Comment: oh I see a . after the -L    mybe that caused the issue...

Comment: Yes you need a period(`.`) to point the linker to current directory.

Comment: thanks did not know  that

Comment: @xetra11 : Also, you need to pack the object files with the archive(`ar`) command **not** the source files.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are linking source files but not object files

```
ar rcs librenderay.a renderay_core.c renderay_shapes.c
```

It must be something like that

```
ar rcs librenderay.a renderay_core.o renderay_shapes.o
```

P.S. You can do this with Makefile

```
CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -fPIC
OBJS = renderay_core.o renderay_shapes.o

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

librenderay.a: $(OBJS)
    $(AR) rcs librenderay.a $(OBJS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) librenderay.a $(OBJS)
```

Comment: ahhhh ok meh kind of a typo. thanks dude